# Java Library for converting a long IPv6 address into its compressed form

Tags: java, ipv6

I would like to know, whether there is a library which I can use to convert a represenation of a long IPv6 address (such as 2002:9876:57AB:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001) into the compressed IPv6 form (in this case: 2002:9876:57AB::1).

I was not able to find such a library. This library should not use any IP Api, a network connection must not be made.

I already tried

```
return Inet6Address.getByName(longAdress).toString();
```

but this just replaces the 4 zeros with 1 zero (in this case 2002:9876:57AB:0:0:0:0:1).

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Ipv6AddressCompressor {
    public static String getCompressedAddress(String longAddress) throws UnknownHostException {
        longAddress = Inet6Address.getByName(longAddress).getHostAddress();
        return longAddress.replaceFirst("(^|:)(0+(:|$)){2,8}", "::");
    }
}
```

This should protect you against invalid addresses (throws the UnknownHostException), and will properly compress trailing ipv4 addresses (i.e. 0:0:0:0:0:0:255.255.255.255 -> ::FFFF:FFFF).  This will also protect against already compressed addresses.

Comment: Except it doesn't remove redundant zeros, e.g., `0000:0000:0001` should be `::1` but becomes `::0001` - fixable by doing something like `replaceAll("(:|^)0+(\\d)", "$1$2")` on the result, though.

Comment: Good catch.  Your \\d should be [0-9A-Fa-F] though.  Will update to fix.

Comment: Caution: Inet6Address.getByName can lead to DNS queries if you feed e.g. a broken address like "::1::" into it. This can take a couple of seconds on a single call!

Comment: following case is not working "0000:0000:000f::0000:ffff" -> 0:0:f::ffff

Answer (score 6):

[java-ipv6](https://code.google.com/p/java-ipv6/) is a very decent library for that. It also handles address ranges well.

Answer (score 2):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do ip address parsing and produce a variety of strings.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Example code:

```
    String ipv6 = "2002:9876:57AB:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001";
    try {
        IPAddressString str = new IPAddressString(ipv6);
        IPAddress addr = str.toAddress();
        String compressed = addr.toCompressedString();
        System.out.println(compressed); //
    } catch(IPAddressStringException e) {
        //e.getMessage has validation error
    }
```

output:

```
2002:9876:57ab::1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It'll probably perform better than the regex equivalent (not that I have benchmarked it, or anything). It's pretty well tested too.

Note that you will need to use a numeric representation (in `byte[]`) of the IP address. To get it you can either do `InetAddress.getByName(ip).getAddress()` if you need to resolve host names, or use sun utility class `IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV6(ip)` to parse from an IP address without host resolution.

```
private static final char[] ipv6conseqZeroFiller = { ':', ':' };
private static final char ipv6hextetSeparator = ':';

/*
 * Convert numeric IPv6 to compressed format, where
 * the longest sequence of 0's (with 2 or more 0's) is replaced with "::"
 */
public static String ipv6toCompressedForm(byte[] src) {
    assert src.length == 16;
    //Find the longest sequence of 0's 
    int cmprHextet = -1; //start of compressed region (hextet index)
    int cmprSize = 0; //length of compressed region
    for (int hextet = 0; hextet < 8;) {
        int curByte = hextet * 2;
        int size = 0;
        while (curByte < src.length && src[curByte] == 0
                && src[curByte + 1] == 0) {
            curByte += 2;
            size++;
        }
        if (size > cmprSize) {
            cmprHextet = hextet;
            cmprSize = size;
        }
        hextet = (curByte / 2) + 1;
    }
    if (cmprHextet == -1 || cmprSize < 2) {
        //No compression can be applied
        return ipv6toStr(src);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(39);
    ipv6toStr(sb, src, 0, cmprHextet);
    sb.append(ipv6conseqZeroFiller);
    ipv6toStr(sb, src, cmprHextet + cmprSize, 8);
    return sb.toString();
}

/*
 * Convert numeric IPv6 to standard (non-compressed) format.
 *
 * Borrowed from Inet6Address.java #numericToTextFormat(byte[])
 * Changed StringBuffer -> StringBuilder and ":" -> ':' for performance.
 */
public static String ipv6toStr(byte[] src) {
    assert src.length == 16;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(39);
    ipv6toStr(sb, src, 0, 8);
    return sb.toString();
}

private static final void ipv6toStr(StringBuilder sb, byte[] src,
        int fromHextet, int toHextet) {
    for (int i = fromHextet; i < toHextet; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(((src[i << 1] << 8) & 0xff00)
                | (src[(i << 1) + 1] & 0xff)));
        if (i < toHextet - 1) {
            sb.append(ipv6hextetSeparator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this from?