# How to convert a hyphenated IP range to CIDR in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a hyphenated IP range, and I need to convert it to CIDR notation, for example:

input: 70.103.242.28-70.103.242.30
output: 70.103.242.28/31, 70.103.242.30/32

Python has a library for it (ipaddress):

```
cidr = ipaddress.summarize_address_range(start_ip, end_ip)
```

Looking for something similar in Node.js, but unable to find it. I would rather use a library for it than implement it on my own. Looked into netmask, ip-cidr, ip6, ip libraries, but it doesn't look like any of those support it.

Comment: a question similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642134/6796856

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It looks like the question you've shared is about checking whether an IP belongs to CIDR range.

Comment: It looks like the npm package `js_cidr` can do what you want -- IF you can expand that input range to an array of ips.

Comment: For the "implement it on your own" way, the set of all CIDR prefixes form a complete binary tree, so you can create a compact set of ranges efficiently using divide-and-conquer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use **[ip-subnet-calculator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip-subnet-calculator)** module:

```js
const SubnetCalculator = require('ip-subnet-calculator');

const ipRange = '192.168.0.1-192.168.0.10';
const [startIp, endIp] = ipRange.split('-');

const subnet = SubnetCalculator.calculate(startIp, endIp);
console.log(subnet);
```

Output:

```js
[
    {
        ipLow: 3232235521,
        ipLowStr: "192.168.0.1",
        ipHigh: 3232235521,
        ipHighStr: "192.168.0.1",
        prefixMask: 4294967295,
        prefixMaskStr: "255.255.255.255",
        prefixSize: 32,
        invertedMask: 0,
        invertedMaskStr: "0.0.0.0",
        invertedSize: 0
    },
    // ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this library which does what I need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cidr-calc

I wish there was a library that had a larger user base, but it's much better than nothing.

```
const { IpAddress, IpRange } = require('cidr-calc');
const ipRange = new IpRange(IpAddress.of('70.103.242.28'), IpAddress.of('70.103.243.255'));
const cidrs = ipRange.toCidrs();
```

Comment: FWIW, this is the answer that ChatGPT proposes as well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I actually tried asking ChatGPT about it about a month ago, and it wasn't able to give an answer (well, it did, but none of them worked)

Comment: That is interesting. Perhaps it had not learned that yet. I literally fed it your entire question, as-is, and it provided a pretty comprehensive answer and a code sample. The options it gave were: ip-cidr, cidr-calc, and get-ip-range.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think there is any package in nodeJS to do this, but you can convert ip addresses to integers and find the maximum bits needs to represent those.

```
const ip = require('ip');

function convert(startIP, endIP) {
    const start = ip.toLong(startIP);
    const end = ip.toLong(endIP);

    const cidrBlocks = [];
    while (start <= end) {
        const maxBits = 32 - Math.floor(Math.log2(end - start + 1));
        const cidrBlock = ip.fromLong(start) + '/' + maxBits;
        cidrBlocks.push(cidrBlock);

        start += Math.pow(2, 32 - maxBits);
    }

    return cidrBlocks;
}

// convert('70.103.242.28', '70.103.242.30');
```

Answer (score -1):

Borrowing the function from the linked question in Michele's comment above, you can convert the `first`-`last` addrs to numbers and then iterate over the number range to create an array:

```js
function addrToNum(addr) {
  return addr.split(".").reduce((acc,cur,i)=> acc += (Number(cur) << ( (3-i) * 8) ) ,0)
}
function numToAddr(num) {
  return [(num >>> 24), (num >>> 16) & 0xFF, (num >>> 8) & 0xFF, (num & 0xFF)].join(".")
}

const [firstIp, lastIp] = "70.103.242.28-70.103.242.30".split("-")
const firstNo = addrToNum(firstIp)
const lastNo = addrToNum(lastIp)
console.info(`Start: ${firstNo}, Stop: ${lastNo}`)

let ipArray = []
for (let ipNo = firstNo; ipNo <= lastNo; ipNo++) {
  let ipAddr = numToAddr(ipNo)
  ipArray.push(ipAddr)
}
console.info(`Array: [${ipArray}]`)
```

Pass this `ipArray` to the CIDR.getBlocks function (untested):

```
const CIDR = require("cidr-js");
const cidr = new CIDR();
let ipBlocks = cidr.getBlocks(ipArray);
```

Comment: While it does seem to work, the code produces ranges that aren't very compact. For example, when I use this range 70.103.242.28-70.103.243.255, I get a total of 13 ranges, with the 70.103.243.0 to 255 range expressed as 9 blocks instead of one block like this: 70.103.243.0/24

Comment: This is extremely inefficient considering that this is an $O(N)$ algorithm on a search space of $2^{32}$.